# How to hide paths to an user in SVN

Tags: svn, synology

I have a repository in Subversion with some folders:

```
Repository
|
|-> Folder A
|
|-> Folder B
|
`-> Folder C
```

And I have the admin user (with all visibility) and want to create a new user with visibility in Folder B only. I have my SVN server installed in a NAS Synology, but I supose than the config is the same.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.general ?

Comment: yes and didn't work, or I don't know how to configure

Comment: How did you try it (please edit your answer)? It should work.